# Find a sequence which has an even number of odd terms, and yet the sequence is not a graph score.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Construct an example of a sequence of length n in which each term is
some of the numbers 1, 2, . . . , n − 1 and which has an even number of
odd terms, and yet the sequence is not a graph score.

Maybe somebody could give me a hint where to start. My guess is that maybe score theorem could be somehow useful, but I'm not really sure how.

Comment: What is a _graph score_ and what is the _score theorem_?

Comment: When you say *graph score*, do you mean the [score sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScoreSequence.html) for a tournament graph?

Comment: I mean the degree sequence of the graph.

Comment: Directed or undirected graph?

Comment: undirected graph

Comment: One last question: do you allow loops or multiple edges, or are your graphs simple graphs?

Comment: Simple gpraphs.

Comment: Then, I would suggest you try to prove, that there is no graph with two vertices of degree one and two vertices of degree $n-1$ if $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try giving all but one of the vertices degree $1$ and giving the remaining vertex a larger degree. (If $n=2$ you can’t find such a sequence, so you can assume that $n>2$.)

Answer (score 0):

Since every edge is counted twice in the degree of a vertex, we have that $\Sigma(deg(G))=$2E(G)$ $

EDIT:
  As was pointed out, I misread; this would work only without the constraint of having an even number of edges of odd degree. Then , any sequence whose sum of degrees is odd, cannot be a sequence. Sorry.

Comment: I missed the ëven number of odd terms part"; I was going for a sequence with sum of degrees an odd number.